# How to make a loop for a function until a bool is true?

Tags: json, loops, flutter, firebase-storage, nested-object

I have a function that gets some info from firebase storage using url,these info contains a bool, what I want to achieve is to loop for a `true` value in each nested object I have in this JSON file and stop when it found a true value.

**Code:**

```
Future getAya() async {
    await checkInternet();
    await down_data();
    if (khatma == 'Khatma 1') {
      var rng = new Random();
      int ranum = rng.nextInt(2);
      var response = await http.get(
        'firebase link',
      );
      var myDataString = utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);
      data = jsonDecode(myDataString);
      if (state = true) {
        print('Taken');
      } else {
        setState(() {
          ranAya = data['verse_$ranum']['Aya'];
          state = data['verse_$ranum']['taken'];
          audioLink = data['verse_$ranum']['audioLink'];
        });
      }
```

Comment: `if (state = true)` should probably be `if (state == true)`

Comment: but it works fine ?

Comment: It will always succeed since you are assigning `true` to `state` instead of comparing `true` and `state`

Comment: ok but what about the question ?

Comment: I'm not a flutter expert but it would appear you are missing some kind of loop structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `do while` loop like this:

```
 Future getAya() async {
  bool state = false;

  do{
    await checkInternet();
    await down_data();
    if (khatma == 'Khatma 1') {
      var rng = new Random();
      int ranum = rng.nextInt(2);
      var response = await http.get(
        'firebase link',
      );
      var myDataString = utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);
      data = jsonDecode(myDataString);
      state = data['verse_$ranum']['taken'];

      if (state) {
        print('Taken');
      } else {
        setState(() {
          ranAya = data['verse_$ranum']['Aya'];
          audioLink = data['verse_$ranum']['audioLink'];
        });
      }
    }
  }while(!state);
}
```

Comment: does this mean it will do what in the do brackets if state = false ?

Comment: what about looping until it finds a state equals false as I have many nested objects.

Comment: I want to repeat this function until I get a state = false

Comment: Yes `while(!state)` does this for you. It repeats your code block until `state` gets true. If you want the opposite set it to `while(state)` @FlutterDeveloper1

Comment: Check your condition in `while` statement. Here you can read more about this type of loops: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_do_while_loop.htm

Comment: This can make the program to go into infinite loop till the `bool` goes true which could freeze the app. Instead, use a `timer` function to check for the `bool` and then if the variable goes `true` just come out of the timer.

Comment: Timer ? why ? I don't want to set a timer, and what if the internet is bad ?

Comment: @R.Shapd this way is good but I am dealing with a random number as u can see up 
      `var rng = new Random();`
      `int ranum = rng.nextInt(2);`

Comment: How can I ensure that the same number will be produced again - Just To A better Performance -.

Comment: As what u don't know that this json file contains more than 6000 nested object :O

Comment: Save your selected objects to check if the new object is selected before or not. If your item list is finite check its length to prevent infinite loop.